# Why does my code not center on iphone only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, 3d, carousel

I created a popup window with a 3d carousel and it works just fine on desktop and mobile. Only on iPhone, it's not centering the content.

I tried several things but they all failed.

Below you can view all my code unfortunately I don't know where the mistake could be so the whole thing is quite long.

`

```
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap');
</style>

<style>
    /*only desktop*/
    .whatGuideD {
    display: none;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .whatGuideD {display: block;
    }
    .whatGuideM {display: none;
    }
    }

</style>

<!-- Demo styles -->
<style>
    html {
        height: -webkit-fill-available;
    }
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      height: -webkit-fill-available;
    }

    .swiper {
      width: 100%;
      padding-top: 0;
      padding-bottom: 50px;
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 0;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      width: 60%;
      max-width: 500px;
      height: 75vh;
      max-height: 500px;
      border-radius: 15px;
      background: rgb(238, 235, 241);
      box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px -1px rgba(10, 99, 169, 0.16),
      -10px -10px 10px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.70);
      -webkit-box-reflect: below 1px linear-gradient(transparent, transparent, #fff6)
      
    }

    .swiper-slide button {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 500px;
    }

    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        Font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
        font-size: 5vw;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .pickGuideD {
        Font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 48px;
        font-weight: 500;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgb(238, 235, 241);
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 10px;
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        border: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .pickGuideD:hover {
        box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 10px -1px rgba(10, 99, 169, 0.16),
       inset -10px -10px 10px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.70);
    }

</style>

<style>
.pickGuideM {
    Font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 500;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(238, 235, 241);
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.pickGuideM:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 10px -1px rgba(10, 99, 169, 0.16),
   inset -10px -10px 10px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.70);
}
.close-button1D {
        background-color: rgb(238, 235, 241);
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 30px;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 40px;
        border: 0; 
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<style>
        .whatGuideD {
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;
    background: rgb(238, 235, 241);
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(15, 15, 15);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 3;
    position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    }
    .whatGuideD.active2{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    }
    .whatGuideM {
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;
    background: rgb(238, 235, 241);
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(15, 15, 15);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 3;
    position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    }
    .whatGuideM.active2M{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    }

</style>
```

`

`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/661fc68da9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
        />
        <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"
        />
    
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/661fc68da9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <button onclick="Size()">Size Guide</button>
    
    
    <div class="sizeGuidance">
        <form data-multi-step2>
            <div class="whatGuideD" data-step2>
                <br>
    
                <h1>The Size Guide</h1>
               
                <div class="swiper mySwiper">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div id="sw1" class="swiper-slide">
                            <span style="--i:1;"><button type="button" class="pickGuideD" onmouseleave="removedisc1()" onmouseover="showdisc1()"><i class="fa-solid fa-ruler fa-3x" style=" display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 15px; " ></i>Quick Guide</button></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <span style="--i:2;"><button type="button" class="pickGuideD" onmouseleave="removedisc2()" onmouseover="showdisc2()"><i class="fa-solid fa-bullseye fa-2x" style=" display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 15px" ></i>Super Guide</button></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <span style="--i:3;"><button type="button" class="pickGuideD" onmouseleave="removedisc3()" onmouseover="showdisc3()"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-poll-horizontal fa-2x" style=" display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 15px" ></i>Size Chart</button></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                    <p id="d1"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <form data-multi-step2M>
            <div class="whatGuideM" data-step2M>
                <br>
    
                <h1>The Size Guide</h1>
                <br>
                <div class="swiper mySwiper">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <span style="--i:1;"><button type="button" class="pickGuideM" onmouseleave="removedisc1()" onmouseover="showdisc1()"><i class="fa-solid fa-ruler fa-3x" style=" display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 15px; " ></i>Quick Guide</button></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <span style="--i:2;"><button type="button" class="pickGuideM" onmouseleave="removedisc2()" onmouseover="showdisc2()"><i class="fa-solid fa-bullseye fa-3x" style=" display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 15px" ></i>Super Guide</button></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <span style="--i:3;"><button type="button" class="pickGuideM" onmouseleave="removedisc3()" onmouseover="showdisc3()"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-poll-horizontal fa-3x" style=" display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 15px" ></i>Size Chart</button></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                    <p id="d1"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`

`

```
<script>
    var disc1 = document.querySelector("[showdiscrip1]")
function showdisc1() {
  disc1.classList.add("disc");
}    
function removedisc1() {
   disc1.classList.remove("disc")
}

var disc2 = document.querySelector("[showdiscrip2]")
function showdisc2() {
  disc2.classList.add("disc");
}    
function removedisc2() {
   disc2.classList.remove("disc")
}

var disc3 = document.querySelector("[showdiscrip3]")
function showdisc3() {
  disc3.classList.add("disc");
}    
function removedisc3() {
   disc3.classList.remove("disc")
}
</script>

<script>
   const mulitStepForm2 = document.querySelector("[data-multi-step2]")
   const formSteps2 = [...mulitStepForm2.querySelectorAll("[data-step2]")]
   
   let currentStep2 = formSteps2.findIndex(step2 => {
   return step2.classList.contains("active2")
   })
   
       if (currentStep2 < 0) { function SizeD() {
           currentStep2 = 0
           formSteps2[currentStep2].classList.add("active2")
           showCurrentStep2();
           window.scrollTo(0,20);         
           }
       }     
   
       mulitStepForm2.addEventListener("click", j => {
   if (j.target.matches("[data-next]")) {
       currentStep2 ++
   } else if (j.target.matches("[data-closeguide]")) {
       currentStep2 = -1
   } 
   showCurrentStep2()
   })
   function showCurrentStep2() {
   formSteps2.forEach((step2, index) => {
       step2.classList.toggle("active2", index ===
       currentStep2)
   })
   }
</script>  

<script>
    const mulitStepForm2M = document.querySelector("[data-multi-step2M]")
    const formSteps2M = [...mulitStepForm2M.querySelectorAll("[data-step2M]")]
    
    let currentStep2M = formSteps2M.findIndex(step2M => {
    return step2M.classList.contains("active2M")
    })
    
        if (currentStep2M < 0) { function SizeM() {
            currentStep2M = 0
            formSteps2M[currentStep2M].classList.add("active2M")
            showCurrentStep2M();
            window.scrollTo(0,0);         
            }
        }     
    
        mulitStepForm2M.addEventListener("click", j => {
    if (j.target.matches("[data-nextM]")) {
        currentStep2M ++
    } else if (j.target.matches("[data-closeguideM]")) {
        currentStep2M = -1
    } 
    showCurrentStep2M()
    })
    function showCurrentStep2M() {
    formSteps2M.forEach((step2M, index) => {
        step2M.classList.toggle("active2M", index ===
        currentStep2M)
    })
    }
 </script> 

 <script>
    function Size() {
        SizeD();
        SizeM();
    }
 </script>

<script>
    const sw1 = document.getElementById("sw1");
    

    sw1.addEventListener("transitionend", function (k) {
        console.log(k)

        if () {
            var num = 1        
            console.log(num)
        }
    })
</script>


    <!-- Swiper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
    <script>
      var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        effect: "coverflow",
        grabCursor: true,
        centeredSlides: true,
        slidesPerView: "auto",
        coverflowEffect: {
          rotate: 50,
          stretch: 0,
          depth: 500,
          modifier: 1,
          slideShadows: true,
        },
        pagination: {
          el: ".swiper-pagination",
        },
      });
    </script>
```

`

Comment: and we should just guess at the html?

Comment: @DCR here you go

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

your html is wrong in a couple of places and your js is wrong with if().  See code below for working snippet

```js
  var disc1 = document.querySelector("[showdiscrip1]")

  function showdisc1() {
    disc1.classList.add("disc");
  }

  function removedisc1() {
    disc1.classList.remove("disc")
  }

  var disc2 = document.querySelector("[showdiscrip2]")

  function showdisc2() {
    disc2.classList.add("disc");
  }

  function removedisc2() {
    disc2.classList.remove("disc")
  }

  var disc3 = document.querySelector("[showdiscrip3]")

  function showdisc3() {
    disc3.classList.add("disc");
  }

  function removedisc3() {
    disc3.classList.remove("disc")
  }



  const mulitStepForm2 = document.querySelector("[data-multi-step2]")
  const formSteps2 = [...mulitStepForm2.querySelectorAll("[data-step2]")]

  let currentStep2 = formSteps2.findIndex(step2 => {
    return step2.classList.contains("active2")
  })

  if (currentStep2 < 0) {
    function SizeD() {
      currentStep2 = 0
      formSteps2[currentStep2].classList.add("active2")
      showCurrentStep2();
      window.scrollTo(0, 20);
    }
  }

  mulitStepForm2.addEventListener("click", j => {
    if (j.target.matches("[data-next]")) {
      currentStep2++
    } else if (j.target.matches("[data-closeguide]")) {
      currentStep2 = -1
    }
    showCurrentStep2()
  })

  function showCurrentStep2() {
    formSteps2.forEach((step2, index) => {
      step2.classList.toggle("active2", index ===
        currentStep2)
    })
  }


  const mulitStepForm2M = document.querySelector("[data-multi-step2M]")
  const formSteps2M = [...mulitStepForm2M.querySelectorAll("[data-step2M]")]

  let currentStep2M = formSteps2M.findIndex(step2M => {
    return step2M.classList.contains("active2M")
  })

  if (currentStep2M < 0) {
    function SizeM() {
      currentStep2M = 0
      formSteps2M[currentStep2M].classList.add("active2M")
      showCurrentStep2M();
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  }


  mulitStepForm2M.addEventListener("click", j => {
    if (j.target.matches("[data-nextM]")) {
      currentStep2M++
    } else if (j.target.matches("[data-closeguideM]")) {
      currentStep2M = -1
    }
    showCurrentStep2M()
  })

  function showCurrentStep2M() {
    formSteps2M.forEach((step2M, index) => {
      step2M.classList.toggle("active2M", index ===
        currentStep2M)
    })
  }


  function Size() {
    SizeD();
    SizeM();
  }

  const sw1 = document.getElementById("sw1");


  sw1.addEventListener("transitionend", function(k) {
    console.log(k)
 
 
    if (1==1) {
      var num = 1
      console.log(num)
    }
  })






  var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    effect: "coverflow",
    grabCursor: true,
    centeredSlides: true,
    slidesPerView: "auto",
    coverflowEffect: {
      rotate: 50,
      stretch: 0,
      depth: 500,
      modifier: 1,
      slideShadows: true,
    },
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
    },
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/661fc68da9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/661fc68da9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="Size()">Size Guide</button>


  <div class="sizeGuidance">
    <form data-multi-step2>
      <div class="whatGuideD" data-step2>
        <br>

        <h1>The Size Guide</h1>

        <div class="swiper mySwiper">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div id="sw1" class="swiper-slide">
              <span style="--i:1;"><button type="button" class="pickGuideD" onmouseleave="removedisc1()" onmouseover="showdisc1()"><i class="fa-solid fa-ruler fa-3x" style=" display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 15px; " ></i>Quick Guide</button></span>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <span style="--i:2;"><button type="button" class="pickGuideD" onmouseleave="removedisc2()" onmouseover="showdisc2()"><i class="fa-solid fa-bullseye fa-2x" style=" display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 15px" ></i>Super Guide</button></span>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <span style="--i:3;"><button type="button" class="pickGuideD" onmouseleave="removedisc3()" onmouseover="showdisc3()"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-poll-horizontal fa-2x" style=" display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 15px" ></i>Size Chart</button></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
          <p id="d1"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <form data-multi-step2M>
      <div class="whatGuideM" data-step2M>
        <br>

        <h1>The Size Guide</h1>
        <br>
        <div class="swiper mySwiper">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <span style="--i:1;"><button type="button" class="pickGuideM" onmouseleave="removedisc1()" onmouseover="showdisc1()"><i class="fa-solid fa-ruler fa-3x" style=" display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 15px; " ></i>Quick Guide</button></span> 
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <span style="--i:2;"><button type="button" class="pickGuideM" onmouseleave="removedisc2()" onmouseover="showdisc2()"><i class="fa-solid fa-bullseye fa-3x" style=" display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 15px" ></i>Super Guide</button></span>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <span style="--i:3;"><button type="button" class="pickGuideM" onmouseleave="removedisc3()" onmouseover="showdisc3()"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-poll-horizontal fa-3x" style=" display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 15px" ></i>Size Chart</button></span> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
          <p id="d1"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
 
  </form>
  </div>
  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot I‘ll test it out in a minute

Comment: unfortunatly it didn't change anything about the layout on iphone devices.

Comment: Don't say something is wrong and then just post a wall of code. What is wrong?

Comment: @Rob The content is not centering on iphone (only on iphone) android phones work perfectly fine. I posted only the css . But then somebody asked me to post everything. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @NoahOnyejese My response was to DCR, not you.

Comment: @Rob alright, can you maybe help me tho?